# Can not install Directiv Angular Drag And Drop List

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have problem with install this package :

https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

in index.ejs I include

```
 <script src="/javascripts/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js"></script>
```

He said

**Add the dndLists module as a dependency to your angular app.** Then I add:

```
var App = angular.module('TodoListApp',  [ dndLists ]);
App.controller('TodoListCtrl', function ($scope, $http, ApiService) {
```

And result is 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRJrl.jpg

What I did wrong?

Comment: Do you have an error in the console?

Comment: No, nothinggggg

Comment: Can you share more code? May be a jsfiddle?

Comment: try with **"dndLists"** (quote marks)

Comment: I think it works, I will continue to see, thanks !

Comment: console help you to find errors. Front end developer always should watch console.